# Tomcat SEVERE: Exception starting filter CorsFilter, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat, cors, catalina

I'm trying to enable CORS for my java servlet with the following class:

```
package com.prosperity.mobile.core;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
            ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        // System.out.println("Request: " + request.getMethod());

        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

        // Just ACCEPT and REPLY OK if OPTIONS
        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

My XML:

```
<filter>    
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.prosperity.mobile.core.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And when I try and deploy the war to the tomcat instance:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter CorsFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.prosperity.mobile.core.CORSFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5485)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sep 21, 2015 11:49:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Sep 21, 2015 11:49:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ProsperityMobile] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Which seems like a pretty obvious error, it's complaining that it's not finding the CORSFilter class.. but it's there, in the correct package and everything?!

As a note: My tomcat instance is located at: C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unzip the war file and triple check the class file is there.

Comment: Nice.. when I unzip my war, NO classes are in the project. The directory structure is there for all my packages but no classes are contained in them.. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: refresh, clean and build - try again.

Comment: Are you using maven? Share your pom.xml and your directory structure.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: I am yes, Kepler Service Release 2

Comment: Urgh.. let me just try re-installing this rubbish IDE

Comment: Your Eclipse Project may be corrupted. Make a copy of your project, delete the project from Eclipse, recreate the Eclipse Project and copy all files again.

Comment: So thanks to JC Carrillo here, having to delete my project and create it from scratch, and copying my classes over again worked. Seems that the project indeed was corrupted.

Comment: Friends don't let friends use Eclipse (or Java, for that matter)